# Why is there a user without profile link, reputation and badges on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, users, deleted-users

When I was looking for a solution to my problem I saw a user on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11604310) with no link visible:

> [image: greyed-out user with no profile link]

What is going on here?

Comment: That is a very well drawn question mark.

Comment: @Andy: I would suspect the work was being outsourced.

Comment: @Andy I didn't use image in my question it is edited another user

Comment: @Andy But thats Martijn Pieters! Do you think that he will draw *bad* question mark?

Comment: Was that question mark drawn with Microsoft paint? Because that's probably one of the best drawn question marks I've seen in a while

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That is a deleted user account. When a user is deleted, any answers (and questions with a score of 0 or up) are [retained under the CC license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post).

With the user account gone, there is nothing to link to anymore, and all reputation and badges are gone with the account. All that can be shown is the original user id of the account that created the post.

Comment: Is this a user deleting their account, or an admin deleting their account?  If it's an admin, this would be removing attribution without the author's consent, which would be a problem if the particular license was for attribution.  IDK if that's the flavor of CC license being used here though. It can be something of a mine field.

Comment: @AaronLS: I don't know. But destroying an account (removing it without consent from the author) is reserved for spammers and obvious troll accounts. I am 99.9% certain this is the account owner requesting deletion.

Comment: @AaronLS When you post to SE you transfer all rights to the post from yourself to SE, so I don't think it would matter.

Comment: @Seth No, you do not transfer your copyright to Stack Exchange when you post here. You retain your copyright, and you agree to license your post to Stack Exchange under CC BY-SA 3.0.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I wasn't really referring to "copyrights". Anyway, I was pretty sure that SE owns all the content posted on their site.. Let me see if I can find my references.

Comment: @Seth This is an old myth that won't die. See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14769/135952) and [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25127/135952).

Comment: damn, with all the licensing system :P !

Answer (score 10):

**One more thing not mentioned:** if a post is migrated from one site to another and a user that comments/edits/asks/answers on that question doesn't have an account on the site it is migrated to, it shows up like they don't have an account.

Like mentioned, it can also be deletion.

Comment: I think their name shows up though (not clickable) if it's a migration though.

Comment: @starsplusplus [misread that at first] but that is true (although some users stick to the userXXXXXX pattern for their username)

Comment: *"some users stick to the userXXXXXX pattern"*  Ughh.. it makes them look like convicts.  What, they can't even think up an anonymous name like 'Annonomus Penguin'? (..that's v. cool, BTW)